# Project Sync fails in Android Studio in plugins.gradle.com, Maven Central and dl.google.com

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I installed Android Studio in 2 different machines at work, and when the project syncs it fails on all of the packages it tries to download either it is from plugins.gradle.com, Maven Central or dl.google.com. ALL FAILS.
However, if I try to download this each one of these packages directly from the browser, it downloads fine.

For example, From gradle build I get the error: Failed  https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.22.3/protobuf-java-3.22.3.pom
But if I take the URL and paste it in the browser, the package gets downloaded.

How can I do to fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Please attach your build.gradle files as well.

Comment: OK. This is the build.gradle on the root: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false
}

Comment: and this is the one on the app folder:   plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.yc2'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yc2"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

Comment: compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation libs.appcompat
    implementation libs.material
    implementation libs.activity
    implementation libs.constraintlayout
    testImplementation libs.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.ext.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.espresso.core
}